# Magento 2 : Custom dropdown for city and state not loading in IE

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, dropdown-attribute, state, city

I created custom city and state dropdown all working fine but in the IE it is not loading.

Can anyone please help.?

Comment: Hello,
Where you want to use these two dropdown attribute ?

Comment: Right now I am checking in my account address section.

Comment: Are used skype ?

Comment: Yes @Tushar I am using skype.

Comment: live:tusharlathiya1996 Please contact me

Comment: not in search please send me request on : mayurasisodia